# Why does the result depend on where we write the return statement

Tags: c

> The set S originally contains numbers from 1 to n. But unfortunately, due to the data error, one of the numbers in the set got duplicated to another number in the set, which results in repetition of one number and loss of another number.
>
> Given an array ***nums*** representing the data status of this set after the error. Your task is to firstly find the number occurs twice and then find the number that is missing. Return them in the form of an array
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> **Input: nums = [1,2,2,4]**
>
> **Output: [2,3]**

Stated above is a problem I've been working on, and I've created a working program for it.It is given below

```
    int hashtable[numsSize];
    int*  target =(int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 2;

    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
       {
           hashtable[i] = NULL;
       }

    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
        {
            if(hashtable[nums[i]-1] == nums[i])
            {   
                target[0] = nums[i];
            }
            else
            {
                hashtable[nums[i]-1] = nums[i];
            }
        }

    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        if(!hashtable[i])
        { 
            target[1] = i+1;
            return target;
        }

    }

    return;
}
```

> Accepted
>
> Your input
>   [1,2,2,4]
>
> Output
>   [2,3]
>
> Expected
>   [2,3]

This gives the required output.

But I've noticed that for the *third loop* if you place the `return` statement as given below it doesn't give the required result.

```
for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        if(!hashtable[i])
        { 
            target[1] = i+1;
        }
       return target;
```

> Wrong Answer
>
> Your input
>   [1,2,2,4]
>
> Output
>   [2,-1094795586]
>
> Expected
>   [2,3]

Why does this problem occur?
Are there other similar problems?

Also please give any further steps to take to optimise the program and, any advice regarding similar problems and such matters is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem you have in the second case is that the return is reached too quickly

```
 for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {//beginning of for loop
        if(!hashtable[i])
        { 
            target[1] = i+1;
            return target;  //target is returned only in case hastable[i] is false
        }

    }//end of for loop
```

means that you return target only when hastable at index i is false.
In the second case:

```
for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
{//beginning of for loop
        if(!hashtable[i])
        { 
            target[1] = i+1;
        } //end of if
       return target;
}//end of for loop
```

there is a situation where in case when the first cell of hashtable is not false then "if" body is skipped and the assignment to target is not performed and target is immediatelly returned on the FIRST pass in the loop, without looping and trying to find a "gap" in hashtable.

Comment: Then if I was to include a break within the if condition in that loop, and take the return statement all the way to the end of the program, then it should work just fine right?

Comment: @chathura indeed, the break inside if body would do the job, it would jump out of "for" loop which is what you want. 
It seems strange to me that return at the end of the program (initial) does not actually return anything meaningful I guess it should return something like empty array to signal that something is wrong (or actually the set is fine). Try testing border cases. I think array [1] may cause a problem. Also you may want to write the program in more generic way - looking for multiple such duplicates. I hope you implemented the validation of input params.